# If condition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Firstly I know nothing about `IF` condition in SQL Server 2008.

I have a table `[AccountHistory]` wWith 2 columns `AccountType` & `Amount`.

`AccountType` can have different values (`Deposit, Withdrawal, Profit,...etc`), I need a query to do the following:

```
If AccountType = Withdrawal Then Amount = Amount * -1
```

For Example:

```
  AcountType          Amount
 -----------------------------
   Deposit             100
   Withdrawal         -150
   Profit              220
   Withdrawal         -200
```

Comment: Sounds like you can do this directly with an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Why i am getting -ve ???!!

Comment: You are getting down voted because you show a complete lack of understanding and/or effort on your part. You are expected to show at least minimal effort on understanding your problem before asking help on Stack Overflow because such basic questions do not add to the value of Stack Overflow. Life is cruel that way sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 update AccountHistory
 set amount = amount * -1
 where accounttype = 'Withdrawal';
```

Comment: I am getting error in ASP page: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Update' Although it's working in the query builder

Comment: yes the query works fine, But i am getting the above error while using this query in an ASP page i dunno why...is there any alternatives?

Comment: double check that you are not using stored proc for your command type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by John Gibb (Totally correct in principle), I would also watch your logic here - Is there any restrictions stopping user inputting negative values in the context of the system?

If not, you may be inadvertently turning negative numbers to positive and getting some very odd results as the data collection grows. Furthermore, this query could only be run once - Once additional data is present, executing it again would then turn the original negative values to positive values.

```
update AccountHistory
set amount = amount * -1
where accounttype = 'Withdrawal'
and amount > 0;
```